# How to programatically (Python) scrape streaming live stock chart ticker data and its indicators

Tags: python-3.x, highcharts, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, finance

I have been working on a personal educational project to scrape stock and indicators' data from live chart of the stocks in Python. It could be from Yahoo Finance or investing.com or other similar websites. I know how to scrape data from basic websites but have no clue on how to scrape data from live charts [**specially indicators**] and store them in numpy array in a meaningful way. Below is the view and link to a sample chart.

[image: Sample chart of Apple Inc. along with the desired indicators]

[Link to the chart view. If same view is not visible click on expand view button on top right corner of the chart block](https://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc-chart)

Any help would be appreciated. A nice to have feature would be the ability to select different timeframes and then scrape data.

[**EDIT 1**]

As per the suggestions given in the comments i tried to use Scrapy but that is not how i want to resolve the issue. What i am trying is to get the data without loading a browser.

Grateful if someone can help.

Comment: It would be preferable to find an API that makes the data you're looking for available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. However, as I mentioned the purpose it to learn the process. Also, as far as I know, these websites do not provide an API.

Comment: You should take a look at https://scrapy.org/, this is a mature web scraping framework

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume for pointing to the right direction. Will definitely take a look at Scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

Use [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/). Start with the [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

Comment: Please add some more context to the pages you're linking to, see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I have tried to use Scrapy but it is not useful for me as i do not want to open a browser. What i want is to scrape data directly into a variable.